# How to make this splash page responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive, html5

I need to create a simple responsive splash page where there is a full background image with a logo, text and CTA on the top half of the image.

The Mobile_View image is how the page looks when shrinking the browser down to a mobile device view.[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[image]

As you can see on the mobile view, the logo is going offpage. I've tried everything i could think off and every "solution" I found online and still cant get it to work.

Also, even in full resolution, it looks fine on a large resolution monitor, but as soon as I view it on a smaller one, it gets cut off like this:

[image]

Here is the code I'm using:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Sign up to Betsson today</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" </script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
html{
    background:url('images/page_background.png') no-repeat center center;
    min-height:100%;
    background-size:cover;
}

 .fullbackground {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;

}

 .container-fluid {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 600px;



}
  body {
    font-size:100%; /* flexible baseline */
}




h1 {
    font-size: 25px; Montserrat, sans-serif;
      line-height: 1.0;
      color: #ffffff;


}

.button{
 max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.logo{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

    </style>

  </head>
<body>

<div class="fullbackground">
 <div class="container-fluid bg-1 text-center">

    <div class="logo">
    <br>
```

-->  Here goes logo
      
      
      
       SAMPLE TEXT LINE ONE **TSAMPLE TEXT TWO**

```
    <img src="images/page_shadow.png" alt="Page Shadow">
  <h1><b>SIGN UP NOW</b> & SAMPLE TEXT FOR DEMO</h1>
  <br>
  <div class="button">
  --> Here would be a link
  <img src="images/company_EN_CTA.png" alt="CTA">
  </a>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm still learning the ropes in responsive design, so please bear with me if it is something stupidly siple that I missed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

PS.I had to remove some links from the code as I dont have enough reputation to do that

Comment: This is off-topic and has been reported as such. Please use this board for Wordpress related code and inquiries. Yours is just html and css.

Answer (score 0):

as I understood you have two parts header, one for register one for logo, in bootstrap 3 :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">logo here</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">Register here here</div>
</div>
```

It will make your header responsive. and if you want that your image be responsive you can do like this in bootstrap 3:

```
<img src="..." class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
```

It will auto-resize base on browser witdh.

for background image I suggest you to use css cover property:

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```